# Postman API's are not working after upgraded Nodejs from 10 to 16

Tags: node.js

Recently we migrated Centos 7 to AlmaLinux 9 and Centos 7 server was using Nodejs version 10 but after migrating to Almalinux we installed Nodejs 16. xx but now when we try to connect API getting the below errors.

error: {statusCode: 422, name: "UnprocessableEntityError", message: "xxx api error!"}message: "xxx api error!"name: "UnprocessableEntityError"statusCode: 422

Can you please help me on this, if is this server issue or nodejs upgradation issue?

Regards,
Umesh

We have tried to check connectivity from source to destination & also verified to check from Postman but getting same issue.

But I'm sure this is not connectivity issue.

Comment: What does your Router / Routes look like? Are you using Express?

Comment: Can you try reverting node back to version 10? If it works that should confirm if it's an issue with Node or not. If your looking for an easy way to switch node versions you can use something like NVM (Node Version Manager) to quickly install multiple versions and switch between them.